# Enumerate countries in various languages ISO 3166 using Win32

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, winapi, localization

Is there a way to enumerate all countries and their ISO 3166 codes using some Win32 API or similar? Preferably, in both English and German.

Comment: I would be amazed if this was a baked-in OS call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows version you target is important, the NLS api was considerably improved for Vista.  EnumSystemLocalesEx() is probably what you are looking for, it returns locales names as a `<language> <REGION>` string where *language* is the lowercase ISO 639 language code and *REGION* is the ISO 3166 country/region identifier.  German or English doesn't matter, these codes are language independent.  Have a look-see at the [NLS api docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318716%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to see what's available.